# NetworkManager Hotspot vs. HostAPD

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, hostapd

It seems that the preferred way of making a AP out of your Wireless NIC is to use *HostAPD*. However, there is an easier and out-of-the-box alternative method that can be done with single command with *NetworkManager*:

```
 nmcli dev wifi hotspot
```

I wonder whether there is any advantage of *HostAPD* versus *NetworkManager's* hotspot

Answer (score 1):

I've been googling for a while about hotspot and finally asked me the same question.
I believe the answer is essentially that NetworkManager is a *new* feature, that shall now be used by all Ubuntu users.

`HostAPD` is based on `ifupdown`, what makes more tools for the same needs.
The only answer I've found is in French (https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/network-manager#desactiver_network-manager_pour_laisser_agir_ifup). According to that, `ifupdown` is a more complete solution but NetworkManager makes the job for major usual needs, if you're not operating very complex network solutions...

Perhaps someone more educated could give a better answer.

Regards,
M.